# Shielding home against WiFi interference

Tags: wireless-networking

I live in a dense urban building with several dozen WiFis in range, so there's plenty of interference and some corners of my rather small apartment have noticeable issues with packet loss.

The 5Ghz spectrum isn't as congested, but it doesn't work well through some of the walls. I do use cables where it's practical.

Would it make sense to install some kind of WiFi shielding on the walls and ceilings, such as a mesh or shielding paint, to limit interference from outside sources?

What kind of mesh would I need?

Comment: If its an issue with range then I suggest using repeaters, But I dont think a certain material will block WIFI interference unless your entire house is made of metal.

Comment: You can consider using Acrylic WiFi home version and see which channels are less congested, then use one of non-overlapping channel, 1-6-11. Other option would be to use repeaters, it wouldn't help much with 2.4 GHz band but it would help with 5 GHz.

Comment: You can buy paint that claims to be conductive RF shielding paint.  Some people claim it works as well as Lisa's tiger repelling rock.  I think I've see homemade recipes too. Google is your friend.  (BTW, just using Ethernet cables would probably be cheaper)

Comment: As @infixed says, try just using cables. Go for CAT6, as they tend to be more heavily shielded against interference.

Comment: I am using cables where it is practical.

Comment: If you live in a country where WiFi devices have only 11 channels at 2.4GHz, you could try to buy WiFi hardware with 13 channels (e.g. from european countries). May not be allowed to use, but won't harm anyone. // if you use 'reflective paint' or whatever might help, it will also reflect your own WiFi radiation. It could make your communication better... or worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a practical question with surprisingly no answers yet.

The problem of wireless interference is becoming increasingly, well, problematic. Everybody's got wifi, even people who don't use it, and everybody's got multiple SSIDs broadcasting, even people who don't need them. For example, I live in a 70s vintage suburban neighborhood and I have 77 wireless networks within detectable range of my living room. This is not counting interference from microwave ovens, home automation devices, legacy portable phones in the neighborhood...

How to solve this problem?

Try these options in order:

1. Adjust your WiFi channels to use the least congested channel. If you have multiple SSIDs, set to automatically choose the best channel they may choose the same channel because it's "least congested" and interfere with each other, so manually set one (like your Guest wifi) to a different channel.
2. Use cable where you can. It's not always practical to use a cable - plugging my Surface in means running cable from my basement to my living room and using a USB hub and USB ethernet adapter. Not practical. But, the more cable you use, the less interference you'll cause yourself. WiFi doesn't broadcast traffic if there's no data to send, so the fewer devices you have connected the better your overall signal quality will be. (There is some overhead from just having a device connected but not in use, but most of the traffic will actually be background traffic like OS updates.)
3. Move your router to a more effective location. If your router is in a corner on the opposite side of your house, it may be worthwhile to run some cable and move it to a more central location where you get better signal coverage. If your router is in the basement, but you spend most of your time in the living room, move the router upstairs.

Beyond those options, levels of practicality drop dramatically. Let's go over a couple of them.

1. Using repeaters. BAD idea. Terrible idea. Also one of the most common "solutions" and becoming ever more common. Repeaters don't actually solve the problem of WiFi interference, they compound it, adding tremendous amounts of signal interference and chatty overhead communication that will interfere with themselves. The original problem is that you have too many WiFi devices broadcasting radio signals everywhere and if you buy repeaters you just added 5 more devices to that jumbled mess. Your signal strength may be higher, but your signal quality will be much much lower. You'll also be making things far worse for your neighbors, who may respond in kind with their own repeaters, making matters even worse. The ONLY way to use repeaters responsibly and effectively is to buy WAPs that allow you to fine tune broadcast power to minimize signal overlap. Some consumer grade WAPs and repeaters have this functionality, but for the most part it requires entering the enterprise networking space. (Side note: I work in IT and we solved a problem for one of our customers who was having terrible WiFi connectivity by reducing their broadcast power and removing one of their WAPs. Their own WiFi was interfering with itself more than the neighboring WiFi networks.)
2. Shielding your home. Costly. In theory you could laminate your walls with Aluminium foil, but the practical benefit from this would probably outweigh the risks. I've not tested it, but it's possible that the foil could have the opposite of your intended effect, acting like a giant antenna and amplifying other signals. (I read a grad paper from MIT years ago where the student tested this with "foil hats" and a receiver inside a mannequin head. He found that the foil amplified radio signals broadcast towards the mannequin. Good times.) A wire mesh around your home to act as a Faraday cage may work, but there's math in determining the size of the mesh required to attenuate a given frequency range, and the cost would be exorbitant. There are radio attenuating paints available, but these run in the range of $250+ for a 5 liter bucket and I haven't actually seen any test results for them.

I will say that if shielding a home were cost effective, it would be the best solution. Attenuating your neighbors' signals instead of boosting your own reduces the cause of interference directly. For my suburban home, painting just the two walls facing my nearest neighbors would have a huge impact on improving my WiFi signal strength. But it's just not cost effective for me.